# I can't finish Kali Linux installation process with ISO

Tags: linux, usb, iso-image, compact-disc, kali-linux

During the Kali Linux installation process, I can't install because I am not using a CD or USB. I am using an ISO from the torrent download. I wasn't connected during the process so I don't know if that has any effect on the process. I tried UNetBootIn on my Windows 8.1 Professional 32-bit PC but that doesn't work. It always says that I need to use a CD or USB for the installation plus it has some weird file locations live dev/sda and something like that. I'm new so I don't know what that means.

What do I do?

Comment: Would you like to have a go at an [edit] and see if you can clarify this question a bit?

Comment: Ok so I have a Windows 8.1 32-bit pc with the Kali Linux 1.0.7 ISO. I cant finish the installation because I have no 2-4 GB dvd's or and USB sticks.

Comment: Finish?  How are you starting?

Comment: Alright, back up. If you don't know what `/dev/sda` is, are you sure you want to be installing Kali? It's not an OS for people who are new to *nix systems, and it ships with some pretty insecure defaults; it's designed to be really good at attacking (providing you already know what you're doing), but as a regular desktop distro I'd recommend against it. Have you at least tried it out as a VM or LiveCD first, to get used to it? I can recommend other Linux distros that would be better for someone new to Linux (my first was lubuntu; it was quite nice, by all accounts).

Comment: ...I suppose I should also clarify what `/dev` is, since I've already given you a hard time about it. Here's a [helpful link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/dev.html) which explains the `/dev` filesystem. For future reference, tldp.org is just generally a pretty awesome reference. And no, I'm not affiliated with the project (although that's more because lazy than because couldn't).

Comment: It's also fun because you can get gems like "On a typical machine, the cost is under 0.2 percent. On a modest system with 64 MBytes of RAM, the cost is under 0.1 percent." That's right. A "typical system" when this was written had under 64 MB. Oh, the comedy.

Comment: Well I wanted to use Kali Linux because I'm a "attacker" in training and I've been using Windows for my software but I heard that Linux (specifically Kali Linux) is better for "attacking". Plus, I have no internet at home and I need to test "attacking"....

Comment: Not in an illegal way though.

Comment: Check `md5sum` for your ISO.

Comment: I know md5sum has some valuable things, but is it a list of file locations, and if it is, what do I do with it?

Comment: please [edit](http://superuser.com/questions/782796/cannot-finish-kali-linux-install-without-cd-or-usb-but-i-dont-use-either) your existing post with information, don't repost your question